# How to getback to wpa2 psk from wpa2 enterprise?

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa2, wpa2-psk

I have just changed the wifi setting from wpa2 psk AES/TKIP to wpa2 enterprise only AES. Because of that, now I'm disconnected from wifi and it requires username and password to connect which I don't have.(I don't have any username,when it was working with wpa2 psk, it just required password.)

I regret what I have done and I want to change every thing back to normal.

Ubuntu 21.04 and windows 11 are available, so if your solution works for any of those ones feel free to mention it.

The router model is **Huawei hg8245h** and the router is currently set to **wpa2 enterprise with AES**. WPS and MAC filter is off.
Also I still remember the previous wifi password and admin gate user and pass(located at 192.168.100.1).

Where should I get required username and password from in order to access wifi then accessing admiration portal?
Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to connect to the router. If you cannot connect wirelessly you will need to connect wired. If there is no way to connect wired (it is a wireless-only router) you'll need to reset the router following the instructions in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPA2/3-ENT requires you to configure a RADIUS server behind the router to authenticate against. You configure users and password on the directory (e.g. Active Directory) that is queried over RADIUS.

If you can't access your router any more, plug in an Ethernet cable.

Comment: thank you very much.